# A is a Hermitian projection if and only if it is an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to figure out this property of Hermitian / Orthogonal projections

"A is a Hermitian projection if and only if it is an orthogonal projection"

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: How do you define the orthogonal projection? Often it is defined by being Hermitian.

Comment: A is a Hermitian projection if A is Hermitian and that A is an orthogonal projection if the range of A is orthogonal to its null space. They have also provided a hint which i dont have any clue about. 

Hint: x = (I-A)x+Ax is a sum of vectors in the null space and range of A. If the null space is orthogonal to the range, then x*Ax = ((I-A)x+Ax))*Ax = x(A*A)x is real for all x.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If $A$ is a Hermitian projection, then $A$ is an orthogonal projection.

Let $u\in\mathcal{R}(A)$ and $v\in\mathcal{N}(A)=\mathcal{R}(I-A)$, that is, $u=Ax$ and $v=y-Ay$ for some $x$ and $y$. Since $A$ is Hermitian, we have $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle Ax,y-Ay\rangle=\langle x,A(y-Ay)\rangle=\langle x,Ay-Ay\rangle=0$. Hence $\mathcal{R}(A)\perp\mathcal{N}(A)$.

> If $A$ is an orthogonal projection, then $A$ is a Hermitian.

We show that if $A$ is not Hermitian, then $A$ is not orthogonal. Assume $A$ is not Hermitian. Then $\langle Ax,y\rangle -\langle x,Ay\rangle\neq 0$ for some $x$ and $y$. Hence
$$
\begin{split}
0&\neq \langle Ax,y\rangle -\langle x,Ay\rangle
=
\langle Ax,y\rangle -\langle Ax+(I-A)x,Ay\rangle \\
&=
\langle Ax,(I-A)y\rangle-\langle (I-A)x,Ay\rangle.
\end{split}
$$
Since the sum of the two inner products is nonzero, it means that at least one of them is nonzero (sum of two zeros cannot be nonzero, right?). Hence there is a $u\in\mathcal{R}(A)$ and $v\in\mathcal{R}(I-A)=\mathcal{N}(A)$ such that $\langle u,v\rangle\neq 0$ and, consequently, $A$ is not orthogonal.

---

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{R}(I-A)=\mathcal{N}(A)$. If $u\in\mathcal{R}(I-A)$, then $u=x-Ax$ for some $x$ and $Au=Ax-A^2x=Ax-Ax=0$. Hence $\mathcal{R}(I-A)\subset\mathcal{N}(A)$. Let $v\in\mathcal{N}(A)$ and consider $v=Av+(I-A)v=(I-A)v$ since $Av=0$. Hence $\mathcal{N}(A)\subset\mathcal{R}(I-A)$.

Comment: I think it should be $\begin{split}
0&\neq \langle Ax,y\rangle -\langle x,Ay\rangle
=
\langle Ax,y\rangle -\langle Ax+(I-A)x,Ay\rangle \\
&=
\langle Ax,(I-A)y\rangle \color{red}{-} \langle (I-A)x,Ay\rangle.
\end{split}$. We can easily show that $\langle Ax,y\rangle =\langle x,Ay\rangle$, if $A$ were an orthogonal projection, and thus arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: @user600016 True. Thanks for pointing it out.